# The borders of the active cell should not extend to adjacent cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

Active cell to be highlighted border, **but if the adjacent cell has colspan or rowspan**, border of the active cell extend the full length of the adjacent cell.

table html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="cell-active"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

active cell css

```
table td.cell-active {
  border: 1px double #36CA2C !important; 
  background-color: rgba(121, 255, 21, 0.1);
}
```

jsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/vcwg38ot/1/

Please help make the border of the active cell was only to itself.

UPD: the Outline helps, but then the left and top border are outside the cell. And if you change the offset, it changes for all borders at once, meaning you cannot change the offset from left and top https://jsfiddle.net/vcwg38ot/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code in Chrome(V 46.0.2490.71 m) and Mozilla(V 41.0.2). It worked very well in Mozilla but Chrome extended the green border. [I think it is chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132). However, You can solve this problem in chrome by giving `border-collapse: separate;` to the `table`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcwg38ot/18/)

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: @ErnestFaizullin You are welcome. [It is chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356132). See [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtJbl/)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem. But I will try to answer with my limited knowledge here. When you have used colspan=3 and rowspan=2 that means you want a single cell which have the width of 3 cols and height of 2 rows. Thus when you are thinking that your cell's border is overlapping or merging actually it is a single cell with 3 times the normal width and 2 times the normal height of a cell.

Thank you.